# No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'displayMessage'

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm following a tutorial from this book:

http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6WtVAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA569&lpg=PA569&dq=%5Bself+displayMessage:+kDenied%5D&source=bl&ots=PSj5Nu_QyI&sig=VHOeJtYHARgMOqSEdREyCtcgxc8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=b2rxUv-iN4WQhQfwxIGYDQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%5Bself%20displayMessage%3A%20kDenied%5D&f=false

But when I put this code into AppDelegate.m I get the error message "No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'displayMessage'", however i'm following the code as it is written.

CFErrorRef error = NULL;

```
switch (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus()) {
    case kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:{
        addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
        [ self useAddressBook:addressBook];
        // Do you work and once your finished..
        if (addressBook != NULL) {
            CFRelease(addressBook);
        }
        break;
    }
    case kABAuthorizationStatusDenied:{
        [self displayMessage: kDenied];
        break;
    }
    case kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:{
        addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion
        (addressBook, ^(BOOL granted, CFErrorRef error)
        {
            if (granted){
                NSLog(@"Access was granted");
                [self useAddressBook:addressBook];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Access was not granted");
            }
            if (addressBook != NULL){
                CFRelease(addressBook);
            }
        });
        break;
    }
    case kABAuthorizationStatusRestricted:{
        [self displayMessage: kRestricted];
        break;
    }
}

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

}

Comment: You need to add the `displayMessage:` method to the app delegate too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is telling you that you are calling the method `displayMessage:` and you have not defined it.

Your book is using this method in section 13.1 but there is no definition of it in that section, however what looks like a suitable definition can be found in section 19.1. That definition displays a string in an alert.

HTH

**Addendum**

The full source of all the examples in the book is available for [download from GitHub](https://github.com/oreillymedia/iOS7_programming_cookbook). The author's definition of your missing method is:

```
- (void) displayMessage:(NSString *)paramMessage
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                message:paramMessage
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}
```

You might want to download the full archive as it looks like other examples may be incomplete as well.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the following instance method:

```
[self displayMessage: kRestricted];
```

Which isn't declared in your subclass of UIApplication (AppDelegate).

To solve this, just implement the `displayMessage:` method:

```
- (void)displayMessage:(id)message
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Any idea on what to put in //do stuff here ?

Comment: @Moe You're the only one that can know that. But did this solve the original problem?

Comment: @Moe If that's the case, please don't forget to mark this answer as correct by clicking the grey "check" next to it.